# Why gigabit LAN speed variating from 1000 Mbit/s to 100 Mbit/s

Tags: router

Given:

- I have a ISP fiber plan at home for 120mbps
- It is connected to PON of RouterA
- RouterA LAN1 is connected to a PC (where based on
  observation always has 1000Mbit/s)
- RouterA WLAN is enabled
- RouterA LAN2 is connected to RouterB WAN

I personally crimp the cable using T-568B on both ends (RouterA LAN1, RouterB WAN). There are times that I saw the RouterA LAN1 speed at 1000Mbit/s. My goal of course is to get that 1000Mbit/s. I tried to recrimped the cable several times, I saw it going 1000Mbit/s and going down to 100Mbit/s again. I'm not sure if there would be other reason aside from the CAT6e cable. Or does it goes down to 100Mbit/s if WLAN and LAN1 clients on RouterA needs higher demand?

RouterA: Huawei HG8245H

RouterB: Asus AX3000

Comment: What did you see in the logs? Are there any unexpected random link downs and/or link speed changes? I almost sure this is physical issue. Either you crimped it bad every time, connectors or cable quality is bad, or the socket inside a device become loose, or PHY itself in the NIC itself is failing. // Also, please reread your question and fix where RouterB is connected. It only appeared in the last line, and it looks completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Cat6e" did you mean 5e? Or 6a?  Cat6a cable can have thicker-gauge wires in it, that requires 8P8C connectors designed for it. Do you have the right connectors for your gauge of wire?

Comment: Yes Cat6e. Yes it's just a crimping issue that a cheap tester can't detect. Thank you guys